# PivotItems with blank crashes

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a macro in Excel to compare a cell with a pivot filter if it is selected:

```
Dim checkUnit As Boolean
checkUnit = False
    For Each p In test
        Debug.Print p
        If (p.Visible And p = registration.Cells(i, 2)) Then
            checkUnit = True
        End If
    Next p
```

This works fine for me but the other person who uses this macro has a problem. I have the language set to English and he has set it to German. Now when the German one comes to the "(blank)" one he crashes on `p.Visible`. In English this is not a problem.

What is different and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Just to make sure that is really p.Visible that crash, can you try this ?:     
 For Each p In test
        Debug.Print p.Visible   'debug
        Debug.Print p.Visible   'debug 
        If (p.Visible) Then
             if(p = registration.Cells(i, 2)) thne
                   checkUnit = True
              End If
        End if
 Next p

Comment: Would need more code to see why it fails on the German Language